# Connecting PostgreSQL with R

Tags: r, postgresql, connection

I'm trying to make a connection to PostgreSQL database in R.

I'm writing this

```
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
```

But in result i have an error:

> Error: Couldn't find driver PostgreSQL. Looked in:
>    * global namespace
>    * in package called PostgreSQL
>    * in package called RPostgreSQL

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Consider the [RODBC](http://www.statmethods.net/input/dbinterface.html) package. First, you will need to install a PostgreSQL driver on your machine and then use the DSN in the R connection parameter.

Comment: Definitely check out [RPostgres](https://github.com/rstats-db/RPostgres) -- another package in the Hadley Wickham-verse -- once you've got your PostgreSQL driver up and running you should be good to go (see repo README).

Comment: Have you tried `RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL()`?

Answer (score 8):

```
drv <- DBI::dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
```

gives me the same error but loading RPostgreSQL

```
library("RPostgreSQL")
```

before making the connection solves it.

Answer (score 1):

**Package Issue**

```
  drv <- DBI::dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
```

When you use this code you must include the library that uses the driver package so it wont give you an error please use this code and i am sure it will work

```
  library("RPostgreSQL")
  drv <- DBI::dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
```

and that will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on debian, following helped:

```
apt-get -y install r-cran-rpostgresql
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when writing a package, and inspired by the above answers I found putting:

```
#' @import RPostgreSQL
```

at the top of any function which used `DBI::dbDriver("PostgreSQL")` fixed the problem.